# hashicorp packer: Is there a way to set/update the image name in the provisioner configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

Is there a way to set the image name in the provisioner?

Right now I am using the chef-solo provisioner. I want to create different images with different names using different cookbooks.

My solution so far is to just create 2 separate packer config json files. But was wondering if there's a way to have a single config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *not* possible to set the image name from the provisioner.

You could however pass in a *user variable* which selects the role you run in your provisioner and which is used in the image name.